# How to avoid elasticsearch break value up into individual terms

Tags: elasticsearch

There has a field used to sort, and the value likes `a-b-c`, but I sort by this field, it does not work.

Here is some response

```
{
  "msg":"a-b-c",
  "ti":"b18265be-67a0-4fa7-974f-8198edd1252a"},
  "sort":["c"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a sub-field for `msg` which will be not analyzed or using `keyword` analyzer. Then, when sorting use the sub-field.

Something like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "msg": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string", 
              "analyzer": "keyword" 
            }
          }
        }
```

And when sorting:

```
GET /test/test/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "msg.raw": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
```